# Dates are not recognized

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have written a conditional formula to recognize two dates (greater than and last than). However, there are a few dates that are returning 'false'. All of the columns are formatted as a date. Can someone please help?

[image: Month Table]

[image: Formula]

[image: Results]

Comment: column formatted as date, but have you verified that any of the "dates" are not strings?  ensure there're no spaces before or after.  another option is to `.texttocolumns` to convert

Comment: Hi.  Please edit your question to post the formula as text not as an image.  Also, please include the cell letters/numbers or tell us which cells are which in the image.  Otherwise it's too difficult to understand what is going on here.  Thanks.

Comment: There were spaces in the cell. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW a VLOOKUP would do this with a lot less typing.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(AQ3,DF:DH,3,TRUE)` Would replace the whole formula.

Comment: If I use a vlookup, how would if find it was between the dates?I thought vlookup were for an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question asked, but as Scott said, the formula you use is much more complex than necessary. If you need to return a number for a date that falls within a period and the periods do not overlap, the following formula can be used:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((AQ3>=$DF$3:$DF$15)*(AQ3<=$DF$3:$DF$15),$DH$3:$DH$15)
```

If you need to process text values, it is more complicated. For example, if 'expired' is the only value (also for dates that do not fit into any period), then we can add the `IF` function to the previous formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((AQ3>=$DF$3:$DF$15)*(AQ3<=$DF$3:$DF$15),$DH$3:$DH$15)>0,SUMPRODUCT((AQ3>=$DF$3:$DF$15)*(AQ3<=$DF$3:$DF$15),$DH$3:$DH$15),"expired")
```